# Shopify Delivery App API

Tags: shopify

I'm a developer and I'm working on my own Shopify app
at the moment. I wanted to ask is there ability to get Product
download URL using API or may be somehow accessing Shopify Delivery app API? I
tried, but it seems that I can not get any info about downloadable
products using API, usual set of data only, like for any other
products. Is it really so, and there is no way to get product download
link using API (product API or may be order API).

Comment: There is no url/download field on Product - see the [API docs](http://api.shopify.com/product.html). Can you elaborate on what your app is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I was talking about this app: http://apps.shopify.com/digital-downloads.  As this app is from Shopify developers I was hoping it will have ability to access its files using API.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You cannot access app data via the Shopify API.